# how to open my android app after installation immediately without clicking on icon?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I wanted to open my app after installation is done. I am looking programmatical way to open it automatically.

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Fortunately, that has not been an option in about a decade, for security reasons.

Comment: I just wanted to do a certain thing after installation I am working in android automation.

Comment: You can't have the app open itself for security reasons as mentioned above, but so you would (could) need to have another (started) app with a BroadcastReceiver that intercepts the "android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"-Intent and starts the app mentioned there.